# Jenkins pipeline using "dotnet test" not working

Tags: .net, jenkins-pipeline, command-line-interface, xunit

The test stage of my Jenkins pipeline is failing.
The following error is in the console:

> C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TestPipeline>dotnet test C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TestPipeline\TestProject\TestProject.csproj
> Befehl oder Argument "C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\TestPipeline\TestProject\TestProject.csproj" nicht erkannt
> Description:
> .NET-Testtreiber

`dotnet test` is mistaking the path as a parameter.
I have configured the pipeline with this script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        dotnet = 'C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout Stage') {
            steps {
                git url: 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\source\\repos\\MySolution', branch: 'Development_2'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Stage') {
            steps {
                bat 'C:\\ProgramData\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\TestPipeline\\MySolution.sln --configuration Release'
            }
        }
        stage('Test Stage') {
            steps {
                bat 'dotnet test C:\\ProgramData\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\TestPipeline\\TestProject\\TestProject.csproj'
            }
        }
```

How can I configure the pipeline so that `dotnet test` is running the test project inside the given path?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is a bug in .net7:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/29543

Workaround by setting windows environment variable with:

```
setx /m DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE "en-US"
```

solved it for me